On the relative growth rates of occupancy times in ergodic theory
Let $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a general measure space, and let $T: X \to X$ be a measure-preserving transformation on $X$. Assume that $T$ is ergodic and satisfies the property that, for any set $A \in \mathcal{F}$ with $0 < \mu(A)$,  there exists a positive integer $k$ such that $\mu(A \cap T^{-k}A) > 0$.
For any $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $t \geq 0,~n\ge 1$, define the set $\mathcal{B}(A, t)$ as:
$$
\mathcal{B}(A,t,n) := \left\{ x \in X : \sum_{k=1}^n \chi_A \circ T^k(x) \geq t \right\},
$$
where $\chi_A$ denotes the characteristic function of the set $A \in \mathcal{F}$.
For $A \in \mathcal{F}$ with $0 < \mu(A) < \infty$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$, define the sequence $\theta_n(A, \alpha)$ as:
$$
\theta_n(A, \alpha) := \sup \left\{ t \geq 0 : \mu_A\left( \mathcal{B}(A,t,n) \right) \geq \alpha \right\},
$$
where $\mu_A(B) = \frac{\mu(A \cap B)}{\mu(A)}$ for $B \in \mathcal{F}$, i.e., $\mu_A$ is the conditional probability measure induced by $A$.
For $A, B \in \mathcal{F}$ with $0 < \mu(A) < \infty$, $0 < \mu(B) < \infty$, and $0 < \alpha < \beta < 1$, I want to show that:
$$
\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac{\theta_n(A, \alpha)}{\theta_n(B, \beta)} \geq \frac{\mu(A)}{\mu(B)}.
$$
First, observe that for any set $A \in \mathcal{F}$ with $0 < \mu(A) < \infty$ and $\alpha \in (0,1)$, the sequence $(\theta_n(A, \alpha))_{n=1}^{\infty}$ increases without bound as $n \to \infty$. Now, to derive a contradiction, assume that there exists a subsequence $(n_k)$ such that
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{\theta_{n_k}(A, \alpha)}{\theta_{n_k}(B, \beta)} = \gamma,\quad \text{where }~0 \leq \gamma < \frac{\mu(A)}{\mu(B)}.
$$
I seem to have encountered difficulty in proceeding further with this concept. Your guidance and insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and assistance.

Your set $\mathcal B(A,t)$ has an $n$ in its definition. Do you want $\mathcal B(A,t)$ to be $\mathcal B_n(A,t)$? And then I'm guessing that the definition of $\theta_n$ would involve $\mathcal B_n$; not just $\mathcal B$?

Is $X$ a finite measure space or an infinite measure space? If the latter, as your post suggests, then you are misquoting the ergodic theorem.

@AnthonyQuas Here $X$ is an infinite measure space, and thank you for pointing out the dependence of $\mathcal{B}(A,t)$ on $n$. I have updated my question accordingly.

In an infinite measure space, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n \chi_A\circ T^k(x)=0$ a.e.

@AnthonyQuas Thank you for pointing that out. I apologize for this oversight.

Interesting question. I feel that it should be true that the random variables $N_A(n)/\mu(A)$ and $N_B(n)/\mu(B)$ approach a common distribution (here $N_A(n)=\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbf 1_A(T^jx)$ where $x$ is distributed according to $\mu_A$), but haven't yet managed to write down a proof. I am thinking about making the, hopefully mild, assumption that $T$ is invertible. And then I would use the ratio ergodic theorem (so that for a.e. $x$, the ratio of the number of visits to $A$ versus $B$ up to $n$ should be $\mu(A)/\mu(B)$). The statement I made would imply a positive answer to your question.
